# Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Api.CommonProtos'

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-vision

I'm working with Google Vision .net API lately and meet some problem. I have an AutoCAD plugin which is a class library project( run in .net framework 4.8 ). I want to integrate Vision API into this project.

I create a simple console app( run in .Net 6.0 ) to test the api at first and I can successfully get text from image. below is my code.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;

var clientBuilder = new ImageAnnotatorClientBuilder()
{
    GoogleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("application_default_credentials.json")
};
ImageAnnotatorClient client = clientBuilder.Build();

Image img = Image.FromFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\test.png");
IReadOnlyCollection<EntityAnnotation> textAnnotations = client.DetectText(img);

foreach (EntityAnnotation text in textAnnotations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text.Description);
}
```

but the same code snippet meet some error in another class library project. error occurs at line:

```
var clientBuilder = new ImageAnnotatorClientBuilder()
{
    GoogleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(credentialsPath)
};
```

the error messages shows

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Api.CommonProtos, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...' or one of its dependencies.
```

In `app.config` I have `bindingRedirect` like following :

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Api.CommonProtos" publicKeyToken="..." culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.7.0.0" newVersion="2.7.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

but it seems like it doesn't work. Can someone give me some tips or suggestion? Thanks!

#### Update--

I tested this code in another console app project run in **.net framework 4.8**, no error occurs.

Comment: Can you try to update your older version of the system ? Hope this issue is related to your environment.

Comment: Do you mean update my `.net framework` version?

Comment: Hi TomTomTom, can you check this [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631099/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-google-apis-auth-version-1-51-0-0-culture-neu) and [LINK1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Api.CommonProtos/#usedby-body-tab) ? 

Hope this helps you resolving the issue.

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thx for your info. had read that stack question but not sure what should try now. i have checked the `app.config` and the `package.config` and all the dependencies used by `Google.Cloud.Vision.V1` and their version are correct. `Google.Cloud.Vision.V1` required `Google.Api.CommonProtos Version >= 2.7.0`, but the error shows that it can' t find Version 2.6.0. i have no idea why is this happened

Comment: Can you check this [Git Hub](https://github.com/googleapis/api-common-protos) link ? Have you added a common protos package provided by google , which can be added as a dependency ?

Comment: yes. I have `Google.Api.CommonProtos Version 2.7.0` in my project as a dependency. which is installed automatically when I install `Google.Cloud.Vision.V1` via NuGet Manager. I would try to reproduce this error in another clear project and find where's the problem

Comment: Hi TomTomTom, can you take a look into this [stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419403/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-exception) and [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419403/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-exception/69898853#69898853).

Comment: thx for your info. have read that but I didn't find `Web` tab in my project properties. after testing for a few days i found that this error occurs only when running in AutoCAD. so I think maybe it's related to AutoCAD environment.